# How do I add html code to a page

Tags: templating

I want to add a Comodo Trust Logo to a Craft CMS website page per the instructions below:

> **Install Code Snippets**
>
> Please insert the following two snippets of HTML
> code into your webpage document. You will need to repeat the process
> for each web page you wish to display the TrustLogo.
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
> var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://secure.comodo.com/" : "http://www.trustlogo.com/");
> document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
> //]]>
> </script>
> ```

How do I access the Craft CMS code in order to add the above JS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To edit the HTML code for your Craft site you're going to want to edit the appropriate template file in your Craft install. If you're running on Craft 2 your template files can be found in `.craft/templates/`; if you're on Craft 3 your templates are found in `./templates/`.

You'll need to look in the Craft control panel and see which twig template the section containing the entry (or page) you're trying to edit references. You'll find that info if you try to edit the respective section in `Settings > Sections`.

I will mention as well, if you're looking to include some code that belongs in the HEAD of the html, you'll probably find that in a "master" twig template that contains the `<head></head>`. Once you find the twig template specified in the section settings in the Craft control panel, most of the time you'll see an [`{% extends %}` tag](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/extends.html) which links back to that "base" template.

Hopefully that helps! I'd recommend maybe reading through the Craft docs, starting with [Templating Overview](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating-overview). Cheers!

Comment: Thank you Jalen!  Unfortunately, I will have to find a Craft consultant -- when I sign into the site, I only see my dashboard with entries, assets, etc - no templates.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you again!  I checked the section and can see the page I want to change; however, there is no code, just boxes.  I am afraid this is something I shouldn't touch -- last thing I want to do is mess up the website :-) I will try to find a Craft consultant.  Thanks!

Comment: @user8055 yeah no worries! I'd be happy to help you with the project if you're interested; just ping me at contact[at]dominion-designs.com and we can discuss...

Answer (score 2):

Find the appropriate template in your `craft/templates` folder, and add it there.

If you want it to appear on every page, you'll likely put it in a `_layout` or shared footer template.

Comment: Thank you Lindsey! Unfortunately, I will have to find a Craft consultant -- when I sign into the site, I only see my dashboard with entries, assets, etc - no templates.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: The templates are physical files. You'll need to FTP into the site (or access the files in another way). It's not accessible directly via the Control Panel.